# Can we move ec2 instances from private subnet to public subnet directly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-vpc, private-subnet

I want to move my ec2-instances from private subnet to public subnet. Is there is a  way to do that other than creating AMI of those instances and then launching new instances from those AMI's and attaching volumes and elastic ips with them?

Comment: Moving instances from one subnet to another is not that straight forward. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236469/how-can-i-move-ec2-instances-to-a-different-subnet And https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/ . You can't do that without creating image

Answer (score 7):

An Amazon EC2 instance is permanently connected to a subnet. (Well, the Primary interface is.)

Some options:

1. You could **modify the subnet** so that the subnet 'becomes' a public subnet (by configuring the Route Table to send traffic to an Internet Gateway). This does not require any changes to the instance itself.
2. You could add a **secondary Elastic Network Interface** (ENI) that *connects* it to a public subnet. You then need to configure the operating system to use the secondary ENI.
3. You could launch a new instance in a public subnet, stop it, detach its disks, then **attach the disks from the 'private' instance**, then start it. It will probably start up okay, and it would then be in a public subnet.